# If $α_n$ is the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix of adjacency of $G$, then there exists $v \in V$ such that $\lceil{\alpha _n}\rceil \leq d(v)$

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory

Show that if $α_n$ is the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix of
adjacency of a graph $G$, then there exists $v \in V$ such that $$\lceil{\alpha _n}\rceil \leq d(v)$$

I tried to prove it by contradiction without success. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, Are you familiar with Courant-Fischer inequalities ?

Comment: Hey! I just search it and I think it means that we can define any eigenvalue of $A$, right?

Comment: It usually leads to lots of interesting inequalities involving eigenvalues. Could you give us some additional details on the origin of your problem ? What do you know / have been taught ?